# Building Zeppelin Fails for versions 7.1, 7,2 and 7.3 on YARN error

Tags: maven, build

I've been trying to build Zeppelin from the source in an effort to try and fix the SSL error.

I tried to build from source, and went back to the basic option of

***mvn clean package -DskipTests***

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-21T21:45:31-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 254M/3182M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

Note: This is the same error that happens with each version and I'm building on a Mac OS X platform.   (Not sure if this has anything to do with the problem.)

I'm trying to solve the issue of implementing SSL  which has a different problem with the 7.2 binary release.

Also note that currently (9/21/2017) the continuous build of the latest release is also failing.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after more digging I found that this was a problem that popped up earlier in the year.

The fix is to make sure that you have git and nodejs installed. 
On Mac OS X, I used homebrew to bring down nodejs (Already had git).

On Centos(Linux), I had recently rebuilt the machine for Centos 7.4 and of course didn't download all of the tools.  After pulling git and nodejs from yum repos, I was able to rebuild version 7.3

So now Zeppelin builds in both environments.

Note: If you can't use the built binary versions, think of compiling your own version as a last resort.

I only went this route because I tried to set up SSL for Zeppelin and I was getting an error over my PKCS12 keys were causing an error. (Which I still have to fix. ) Something I hope will work in 7.3